# Using an expression a(1) = 10 instead of a.set(1,10) in Scala

Tags: scala, syntactic-sugar

I can use `apply` in Scala to overload the `()` operator.

```
class A {
    val arr = Array[Int](1,2,3,4,5)
    def apply(i:Int) = {
        arr(i)
    }
}
object Main extends App {
    val a = new A
    println(a(0))
}
```

When I set the value, I can add the set method

```
def set(i:Int, value:Int) = {arr(i) = value}
...
arr.set(3, 10)
```

Does Scala allow better syntactic sugar such as `arr(3) = 10` to get the same results?

Comment: You know, you could just write `arr(3) = 10` and the compile error will contain the name of the method that you are missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could define the [`update`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/sets.html#operations-in-class-mutableset) method:

```
scala> class A {
     |     val arr = Array[Int](1,2,3,4,5)
     |     def apply(i: Int) = {
     |         arr(i)
     |     }
     |     def update(i: Int, x: Int) {
     |         arr(i) = x
     |     }
     | }
defined class A

scala> val a = new A
a: A = A@7d117aef

scala> a(0)
res0: Int = 1

scala> a(0) = 42

scala> a(0)
res2: Int = 42
```